# Flask: current page in request variable

Tags: flask, jinja2

In a template, how do I get what page I'm currently on? I'd rather not pass a variable like `page` , especially when I know some `request.xxx` can provide me with the information.

```
<li {% if page=="home" %}class="active"{% endif %}>                   
    <a href="/">Home</a>                                                
</li>                                                                 
<li {% if page=="about" %}class="active"{% endif %}>                  
    <a href="/about">About</a>                                          
</li>
```

Answer (score 73, accepted):

As long as you've imported `request`, `request.path` should contain this information.

Comment: Note that this is not true for other variables. It works because `request` is one of the variables [inserted by default](http://flask.readthedocs.org/en/latest/templating/#standard-context) into the template context.

Answer (score 66):

Using request.path doesn't seem to be a proper approach since you'll have to update the paths in case of changing URL rules or deploying your site under a subfolder.

Use request.url_rule.endpoint instead, it contains actual endpoint name independent of actual path:

```
(Pdb) request.url_rule.endpoint
'myblueprint.client_pipeline'
```

In a template:

```
<li {% if request.url_rule.endpoint == "myblueprint.client_pipeline" %}class="active"{% endif %}>Home</li>
```

Good luck!

Comment: This is the correct answer. The others use hardcoded paths, which is a very bad idea.

Comment: This only works you are using one route per section of the page. Otherwise this won't be what you are looking for. =\

Comment: No, that's not true. You can have some structure in your endpoint names (like blueprint.subsection.page) and make the comparison using .startswith('blueprint.subsection.'). Just an example.

Answer (score 50):

First import request from flask in your application. Then you can use it without passing to template:

```
<li {%- if request.path == "/home" %} class="active"{% endif %}>
    <a href="/">Home</a>
</li>
<li {%- if request.path=="/about" %} class="active"{% endif %}>
    <a href="/about">About</a>
</li>
```

Comment: `request` imported (into `*.py` file), still getting error: jinja2.exceptions.UndefinedError: 'request' is undefined

Answer (score 12):

To avoid using hard-coded URLs you can use the `url_for` function like this:

```
{% for ni in ['index', 'foo', 'bar', 'baz'] %}
<li {%- if request.path == url_for(ni) %} class="active"{% endif %}><a href="{{ url_for(ni) }}">{{ ni | capitalize }}</a></li>
{% endfor %}
```

In this case index, foo, bar and baz would be function names, used like this in your python code:

```
@app.route('/')
def index():
```

Answer (score 5):

Try

```
<li {% if request.endpoint == "blueprintname.routename" %}class="active"{% endif %}>Home</li>
```

This one worked for me.

Answer (score 1):

You can also use **.split** if your url has more stuff in it.

Example:

/product
/product/add
/product/32432/edit
/product/32432/view

```
{{ request.path.split('/')[1] }}
```

This will return only "product"