# request.path and url_for don't match up in Flask under mod_wsgi

Tags: python, flask, mod-wsgi

In Flask, is there a way to get the request.path that includes any "decorations" that `WSGI` or something else may add on?

Running in the test mode (just on port 5000), my `request.path` and `url_for('settings')` match up just fine, but once under `WSGI`, as expected, my `url_for('settings')` becomes `/manage/settings/`, but the `request.path` yeilds `/settings/`.

I have the following in my `httpd.conf` and am working on moving an [application](https://github.com/FernFerret/servermanager) from development into a live site.

```
WSGIScriptAlias /manage /sw/servermanager/servermanager.wsgi
WSGIDaemonProcess servermgr user=user group=grp threads=4
<Directory /sw/servermanager>
    WSGIProcessGroup servermgr
    WSGIApplicationGroup %{GLOBAL}
    WSGIScriptReloading On
    Order deny,allow
    Allow from all
</Directory>
```

I like the idea of having the templates be pretty generic and then display the navigation information on the fly using CSS. I've used the technique provided in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8676455/flask-current-page-in-request-variable/8676486#8676486) to structure my views to this point, but the issue arises when I add `mod_wsgi` into the equation.

I took a look around the request object and didn't see as much as I'd like other than possibly using the `url_rule` but then the parameters evaded me.

Just for good measure, a link for the WSGI Script that I'm using: https://github.com/FernFerret/servermanager/blob/master/servermanager.wsgi

I'd also be interested in the documentation for the `request` object, I found my way around it by using the built in debugger and `help(request)`.

EDIT: I should say, that the urls don't match up under Apache running mod_wsgi.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

That's a *feature*, not a bug. Check out documentation [for the URL-related attributes on the request](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/api/#flask.Request.path) and [for the request object itself](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/api/#incoming-request-data).

You may want to use `request.script_root + request.path`.

Comment: Never said it was a but :) I can totally see the use of having them individually, must've been late when I was perusing the docs/``help()``.