# How to get current URL in jinja2/flask (request.url not working)

Tags: python, flask, jinja2

Is there a way to print the current URL in Jinja2/Flask?

E.g. if the current URL is `http://www.domain.com/example/1/2`

`{{ request.path }}` works and prints `/example/1/2`, but how to I get the full URL with http:// as well?

From the docs [(here)](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/0.10/api/#flask.Request.url)`{{ request.url }}` should work, but it doesn't yield anything.

Thanks

**UPDATE**

Here are the render/context args from views.py:

```
class EventDetailView(EventObjectMixin, FormView):
    template_name = 'gig/public/about.html'
    context_object_name = 'event'
    form_class = EventPurchaseTicketForm

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super(EventDetailView, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)

    ...

        return context
```

Comment: Does `{{request.path}}` actually work **in your template?** You might simply be missing `request` in your context. Please show us the code that calls the Jinja template's render method (or at least the code that generates the context for it).

Comment: Yes, it works. I am editing someone else's code - where is the render method usually found? In models.py?

Comment: More likely in the view code (the request handler with the logic for that URL)

Comment: Ok, thanks, what would the typical function/argument be that I'm looking for?

Comment: Anything that says `render`, `render_template`, or `context` is likely.

Comment: Unfortunately this isn't really helpful. We'd need to see the code for the original `get_context_data` method, as well as where that context is used.

Answer (score 45, accepted):

You can use `{{ url_for(request.endpoint) }}`, it works.

Comment: Note that you get an error if the route associated with `request.endpoint` requires a few parameters. This [answer to a similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25013141/4453460) provides a better idea.

Comment: @lfurini this can also be solved by doing 
`{{ url_for( request.endpoint, **request.view_args)}}`

Answer (score 36):

For folks who have routes that require additional arguments, the accepted answer won't quite work, as mentioned by @lfurini.

The following will use the view's arguments when constructing the URL:

```
{{ url_for(request.endpoint, **request.view_args) }}
```

Comment: Better than accepted answer for me.  The **request.view_args was helpful

Answer (score 2):

Find where you have similar code to this, usually found in *controller.py* or *__ init__.py* or *views.py* :

```
from flask import render_template
...

@app.route('/example/<arg1>/<arg2>')
def some_view_function(arg1, arg2):
    ...

    return render_template('path/to/your/template.html')
```

With `render_template()` are request and other variables available to you.